# Probability that the last red ticket is withdrawn before the last blue ticket.

Tags: probability

A hat contains $n_r$, $n_b$, $n_g$ red, blue, and green tickets. What is the probability that the last red ticket is withdrawn before the last blue ticket? Does this probability change if we were given the information that the last ticket withdrawn is the green ticket?

I'm trying to think about the first question first.

Let $T_r$, $T_b$, $T_g$ denote the draw at which the last red, blue, or red ticket is withdrawn. We know that 1 of $T_r$, $T_b$, $T_r$ has to be $n_r + n_b + n_g$. The thing I am wondering is if we even need to consider the green tickets at all in determining the probability of the last red ticket being withdrawn before the last blue ticket? If we can disregard the green tickets, then the answer is simply $\frac{n_b}{n_r+n_b}$, but if it is not, then I'm having some trouble of thinking of a non-messy to find the probability, which I'm thinking of attempting by using permutations and combinations.

If we're given that the last ticket withdrawn is the green ticket, then we know that $T_g = n_r + n_b + n_g$. I think my thoughts on whether this changes the probability depends on to my previous question "The thing I am wondering is if we even need to consider the green tickets at all in determining the probability of the last red ticket being withdrawn before the last blue ticket?" If the answer to this question is that we don't need to consider the green tickets, then knowing that the green ticket is the last ticket withdrawn will not change my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine drawing all the tickets as before but looking at them in reverse order.  The question becomes whether the first non-green ticket is blue.  Stated this way, it seems clear you can ignore the green tickets and the chance is just as you say.

Comment: Ah yes, when you put it this way, it sounds so much simpler than thinking about the last ticket being red or blue. The information that green ticket is the last ticket doesn't change the answer right because the event of the last ticket being withdrawn is green is independent or whether the last blue or red ticket is withdrawn first?

Comment: That is correct.